# Rails Search and add filters to the search - geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like some advices on the way to add a filter , on my search form with geocoder.

I got a **User model** and **Animal model** (animals got a Type argument)

 And a **join table** : **Animal_User** with *Animal_ID / User_ID*)

Right now, I can locate Users around a city with the choice of Kilometers around that city.That's working fine.

I would like to add the filter on the type of animal, that would be great :)

**Search would look like this** : London > 10KM > Filter on Type : dogs

Many thanks in advance if you have a glimpse of an idea on how to do that. You will find the search html and the controller. If you need User Model or Animal model i can post it too ( it's really standard Has_many / has_many though association)

search.html.erb

```
<div class="search-bar">
<%= form_tag search_path, :class => "webdesigntuts-workshop", method: :get do %>
  <%= label :user, "" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city], placeholder: 'City', :input_html => { :value => 'Paris' } %>

  <%= label :distance, "" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :distance, params[:distance], placeholder: 'km', :input_html => { :value => '10' } %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

search controller

```
class SearchsController < ApplicationController
    def search
    if params[:city].present?
      @searchs = User.near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10).where("id != ?", current_user.id)
    else
      @searchs = User.all.where("id != ?", current_user.id)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I'm basing it on [Active Record Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins):

```
User.joins(:animals).where(id:  current_user.id, animals: {type: params[:animal_type]}).near(params[:city], params[:distance] || 10)
```

This assumes that your User model has_many :animals (being able to write Rails models DSL like this is awesome)

Comment: I think it worked, Thank you very much , I have to test it a little more but it's one of the best answer I found, very simple and efficient ;)

Comment: I just have a question concerning the '.where(id: current_user.id' , I think it's returning only myself when I am logged in . So in the result it displayed only the current_user and not the differents other users.  I tried this '.where("id != ?", current_user.id)' but it's not working. Thanks you, i am close ;) , I will keep searching on that

Comment: Oh, current_user is usually a method provided by your authentication system, and it indeed returns the user currently logged in. I've copied that parameter from your question. Just add a users collection select to your search form and use something in line with params[:user_id] instead of current_user.id if you are going to search by other users.

Comment: Actually I just removed it and it worked perfectly, thanks again for your help !!

Comment: Fine, if that's what you needed. Just for clarification: using '.where("id != ?", current_user.id)' will match users EXCEPT current_user. It literally means "where user's id is not equal to number passed as parameter".

Comment: That's what i thought but when I pass the parameter ' "id != ?", current_user.id" ' it returns an error _ wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: id != ? _; because it's not expecting other parameter like 'animals:' I will try again later on :)

Comment: That probably happens because you mix Array and Hash conditions in this case. See the Rails Querying documentation I referenced earlier for detailed description of different types of conditions.